# Implementing IEnumerable in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, ienumerable, linq-to-objects

I have this class:

```
public class Detail
{
    public Detail() { }
    public Detail(Guid Id, DateTime InstanceDate, string Name)
    {
        CId = Id;
        StateInstanceDate = InstanceDate;
        StateName = Name;
    }

    public Guid CId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StateInstanceDate { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

and this how I am trying to access data using LINQ:

```
public List<Detail> Getinfo()
{
    CaseContext cs = new CaseContext();
    var query = (from p in cs.table1    
                join q in cs.table2  
                 on p.StateKey equals q.StateKey 
                 select new Detail
                 {
                     p.CId,
                     p.InstanceDate,
                     q.StateName
                 }).ToList<Detail>();

    cs.Dispose();
    return query;
}
```

But I am getting this error,

> Cannot initialize type 'Detail' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BrokenGlass answered your Detail-initialization question but I'd like to add one more thing about your use of the Disposable pattern. Consider coding like this:

```
public List<Detail> Getinfo()    
{  
    using (CaseContext cs = new CaseContext())
    {
        return (from p in cs.table1     
                join q in cs.table2   
                  on p.StateKey equals q.StateKey  
                  select new Detail 
                  ( 
                      p.CId, 
                      p.InstanceDate, 
                      q.StateName 
                  )
               ).ToList(); 
    }
}
```

Using will call cs.Dispose() even if your query throws.

One other thought - consider typing your function like so...

```
public IList<Detail> Getinfo()
```

in case you use a different kind of IList-implementor, or even better:

```
public IEnumerable<Detail> Getinfo()
```

which is even more flexible as long as you don't need IList-y stuff.

Answer (score 8):

You have to either assign the properties correctly or use the constructor:

```
select new Detail( p.CId, p.InstanceDate, q.StateName)
```

Or

```
select new Detail 
{
  CId = p.CId, 
  StateInstanceDate = p.InstanceDate, 
  StateName = q.StateName 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your initialiser, the syntax you are currently using is for a collection initialiser, not an object initialiser:

```
new Detail 
{ 
    CId = p.CId, 
    StateInstanceDate = p.InstanceDate, 
    StateName = p.StateName 
};
```

Or use the other constructor:

```
new Detail(p.CId, p.StateInstanceDate, p.StateName);
```

I think where you falling over is that the compiler is smart enough to handle something like:

```
new Detail
{
    p.CId,
    StateInstanceDate = p.InstanceDate,
    p.StateName
};
```

By infering the property names through the property names of the source type. Notice that you'd have to be explicit about `StateInstanceDate` because `InstanceDate` is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting mixed halfway between two forms of initialisation, you could use the constructor, like so:

```
new Detail(p.CId, p.InstanceDate, q.StateName)
```

Or use property initialisation after the default construct like this:

```
new Detail { CId = p.CId, StateInstanceDate = p.InstanceDate, StateName = p.StateName }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select new Detail(p.CId, p.InstanceDate, q.StateName);
```

or

```
rselect new Detail 
{
    CId = p.CId, 
    StateInstanceDate = p.InstanceDate, 
    StateName = q.StateName 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the section here:

```
select new Detail
           { p.CId, p.InstanceDate, q.StateName }
```

You probably want to use parens instead of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Trirand.Web.Mvc;

enter code here

namespace sample.Models
{
    public class PersonalModel
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public JQGrid OrdersGrid { get; set; }

```
    public PersonalModel()
    {            

        OrdersGrid = new JQGrid
                         {
                             Columns = new System.Collections.List()
                            {
                                 new JQGridColumn { DataField = "PersonId", 
                                                    // always set PrimaryKey for Add,Edit,Delete operations
                                                    // if not set, the first column will be assumed as primary key
                                                    PrimaryKey = true,
                                                    Editable = false,
                                                    Width = 50 },                                    
                                 new JQGridColumn { DataField = "FirstName", 
                                                    Editable = true,
                                                    Width = 100 },
                                 new JQGridColumn { DataField = "LastName",                                                         
                                                    Editable = true,
                                                    Width = 100, 
                                                    },
                                 new JQGridColumn { DataField = "Address", 
                                                    Editable = true,
                                                    Width = 75 },
                                 new JQGridColumn { DataField = "City",
                                                    Editable =  true
                                                  }                                     
                             },
                             Width = Unit.Pixel(640),
                             Height = Unit.Percentage(100)
                         };

        OrdersGrid.ToolBarSettings.ShowRefreshButton = true;            
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to put () after new Detail and then you have to assign properties like CId = p.CId...

Comment: The `()` is not required when using object initialization syntax.  So this answer is flat-out wrong.

Comment: if you use new Detail(){} you have to name the properties: `{ CId = p.CId // and so on`

Comment: parens are optional when using object initializer syntax.  Let resharper into your life.